# How to resize two btrfs partitions (increase the first and decrease the second)?

Tags: linux, partition, btrfs

I have two btrfs partitions, one for /home and the other for root.

[image: gparted screenshot]

**I want to take some storage from the root partition and use it in the /home partition.**

I tried to decrease the root partition size, but I was unable to add the resulting unallocated space to /home partition, because the unallocated space is placed after the root partition.

Comment: Not exactly what you want, but you could btrfs format a new partition in the space freed from shrinking the root partition and then `btrfs device add ...` the newly formatted partition to your `/home` path.

Answer (score 0):

Before you do anything, verify that you have a *working* and *up-to-date* backup of all important data on the drive. You won't lose it if you do everything correctly but you should always have backups anyways and you might do it.

---

My recommended procedure:

1. Shrink the root partition such that the free space behind it is as large as the new root should become
2. Create new partition in that free space (`/dev/nvme0n1pN` where N is the new partition's auto-assigned number. Likely 8.)
3. Mount root at `/anymountpointhere` (if it's not mounted at `/` already; you could do this from a live system)
4. `btrfs replace start /dev/nvme0n1p7 /dev/nvme0n1pN /anymountpointhere`
5. Delete the old root partition
6. Expand home partition

---

You might want to consider merging the partitions. That way you won't have to worry about juggling partition sizes.
The easiest way would be a reinstall but the next best thing is sending the home partition's subvolume (make a snapshot of it) to the root and changing fstab to mount home from a subvolume in the root partition.
Then do the same `btrfs replace` procedure I described above but the other way around to use all your space for the combined partition.